# Apache Commons StringUtils.join creating strange square brackets, commas and whitespacing in output

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

Java 11 here. I am trying to use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join` to take a list of strings and join/concatenate them into a single string, separated by an `@` sign. If there is only one (1) string in the list, then the joins/concatenated output should be that same string, no delimiter. Hence:

- If inputList string is `[ "Hello", "World" ]`, output should be `"Hello@World"`
- If inputList string is `[ "Hello" ]`, output should be `"Hello"`

My best attempt thus far is:

```
String output = StringUtils.join("@", inputList);
```

But for an `inputList` of `[ "Hello", "World" ]` this gives me output of:

```
@[Hello, World]
```

And for an `inputList` of `[ "Hello" ]`, this gives me output of:

```
@[Hello]
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Comment: Of course, you don't need a third party library to do that: `String s = stringList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("@"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method itself works, you just need to put in the array first, then the delimiter. In the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join-java.lang.Object:A-char-) there is an example, and when I just tried it it worked.

The following code outputs `Hello@World`, I just switched the parameters.

```java
    String[] inputList = new String[] { "Hello", "World" };
    String joined = StringUtils.join(inputList, "@");
    System.out.println(joined);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong order of arguments.
You will need to pass the array as a first argument and delimiter as the second argument.

Some sample examples outputs are like this:

```
StringUtils.join(null, *)                = null
StringUtils.join([], *)                  = ""
StringUtils.join([null], *)              = ""
StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "--")  = "a--b--c"
StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], null)  = "abc"
StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], "")    = "abc"
StringUtils.join([null, "", "a"], ',')   = ",,a"
```

The definition of join method is:

```
public static String join(final Object[] array, final String delimiter) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return join(array, delimiter, 0, array.length);
}
```